# UPDATE EN ORACLE CON CONDICIONES DE 2 TABLAS DIFERENTES

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, oracle, update

estroy tratando de hacer un update con las condiciones de 2 tablas diferentes:
este es el query:

```
 UPDATE UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA SET UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO_SEG ='A' 
FROM UZGTFORMULARIOS f, UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p 
WHERE p.SPRIDEN_PIDM= '2401' AND f.UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >=(current_Date)
```

Al ejecutar el query aparece el siguiente error:
Error SQL: ORA-00933: comando SQL no terminado correctamente
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

me prodian ayudar o decir que fatla para que el comando sql termine correctamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿Cual es la relación entre ambas tablas? Por favor, proporciona más información para que podamos ayudarte mejor. De primeras, decirte ya que la estructura básica de lo que quieres hacer parece ser:

```
UPDATE UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA
SET UZGTFORMULARIOS_ESTADO_SEG = 'A'
WHERE SPRIDEN_PIDM = '2401'
AND [campo relacion de UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA] = (SELECT [campo relacion de UZGTFORMULARIOS]
                                                  FROM UZGTFORMULARIOS
                                                  WHERE UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN >= current_Date)
```